# Is it possible to use RDF schema to define a specific Schema.org 'audience' with Microdata?

Tags: rdf, schema.org, microdata, rdfs

I have been heavily using Microdata in my real-estate website trying to guide search engines on how to consume my website. I am trying to understand Schema.org's [`Audience`](https://schema.org/audience) type and see if I can use it to help to target a specific audience.

Here are examples of the audience that I would want to attract to my website:

1. Investors from Asia that are looking to buy a home in New York
2. People from New York that are looking to buy a home
3. Homeowners that are looking to sell their home

How can I specify this type of audience using the `Audience` schema? I am thinking I would somehow need to use RDF schema to define such a thing. But if that is the case, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the properties `audienceType` and `geographicArea` of Schema.org to represent your needs. `audienceType` is plain text, so you can add whatever you want, although it's better to have short descriptions such as "investor".

For example, with your three points I created the following snippet in JSON-LD:

```json
{
  "@context":"http://schema.org",
  "@type":"CreativeWork",
  "audience":[
    {
      "@type":"Audience",
      "audienceType":"People that are looking to buy a home", 
      "geographicArea":{
        "@type":"AdministrativeArea",
        "name":"New York"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type":"Audience",
      "audienceType":"Investors", 
      "geographicArea":{
        "@type":"AdministrativeArea",
        "name":"New York"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type":"Audience",
      "audienceType":"Homeowners",
      "geographicArea":{
        "@type":"AdministrativeArea",
        "name":"New York"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

It's not Microdata, but you can insert it in your main page by doing:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"CreativeWork","audience":[{"@type":"Audience","audienceType":"People that are looking to buy a home", "geographicArea":{"@type":"AdministrativeArea","name":"New York"}},{"@type":"Audience","audienceType":"Investors", "geographicArea":{"@type":"AdministrativeArea","name":"New York"}},{"@type":"Audience","audienceType":"Homeowners", "geographicArea":{"@type":"AdministrativeArea","name":"New York"}}]}</script>
```

And it should be ready to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Since the `audienceType` property is text, how will search engines understand it? Could this impact the site negatively from a SEO point of view?

Comment: You can use the Google structured data tool to see how they would understand your pages, when annotated: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool. As per how they would treat the results for SEO, I am not sure, sorry.